# Radial limits of composition of functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it true that if $f\in H(U)$ is a holomorphic function whose nontangential limits exist a.e and $g\in H^\infty(U)$ is a nonconstant holomorphic function whose range is in $U$ and whose radial limits exist everywhere, then the radial limits of $f\circ g$ exist a.e? I have been trying to show that g approaches its radial limits from nontangential regions, but I haven't been able to prove anything.